# <video> makes text/div dissapear

Tags: html, css

When using a `video` inside of CSS Grid, my text `.name` dissapears, which does not happen when using an `img`

I have set up a gallery, in which projects are going to be displayed:

```
<div class="project"> <!-- Project 11 -->
  <video class="item" src="./images/motiondesign/11.mp4" alt="Project #11" controls loop>
  <div class="name">
    <h3>trippy</h3>
    <p class="date">november 2019<p>
    <p class="description">Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="project"> <!-- Project 10_2 -->
  <img class="item" src="./images/motiondesign/10_2.png" alt="Project #10_2">
  <div class="name">
    <h3>sadness</h3>
      <p class="date">november 2019<p>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and formatted them in CSS as follows (inside a grid):

```
.gallery-site .container .gallery .project .item{
  align-self: start;
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.gallery-site .container .gallery .project .name {
  align-self: start;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

Thank y'all in advance!

Comment: at first glance, you haven't closed the video tag

Comment: OMG, yes. Thank you!